# psql, can't copy db content to another - cannot run inside a transaction block-

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I'd like to copy the content of my local machine to my remote one (inside a docker).
For some reason, it is more complicated that I was expected:
When I try to copy the data to the remote one, I get this `"ERROR:  CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block".`

Ok... So I get into my docker container, added the rule `\set AUTOCOMMIT` inside. But I still get this error.

This is the command I did:

```
// backup
pg_dump -C -h localhost  -U postgres woof | xz >backup.xz
```

and then in my remote computer:

```
xz -dc backup.xz | docker exec -i -u postgres waf-postgres psql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on --single-transaction
```

But each time I get this "CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block" no matter what I try. Even if I put the autocommit to "on".

Here my problem: I don't know what a transaction block is. And I don't understand why copying one db to another need to be so hard pain: My remote db is empty. So why there is so much fuss and why psql just can't force what I want?

My aim is just to copy my local db to the remote one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what happens here is: you add `CREATE DATABASE` statement with `-C` key and then try to run `psql` with `--single-transaction`, so the content of script are wrapped to `BEGIN;...END;`, where you can't use `CREATE DATABASE`

So iether remove `-C` and run `psql` against existing database, or remove `--single-transaction` for `psql`. Make decision based on what you really need...

from `man pg_dump`:

> -C
>
> --create
>
> Begin the output with a command to create the database itself and reconnect to the created database. (With a script of this
>   form, it doesn't matter which database in the destination installation
>   you connect to before
>              running the script.) If --clean is also specified, the script drops and recreates the target database before reconnecting to
>   it.

from `man psql`:

> --single-transaction
>
> This option can only be used in combination with one or more -c and/or -f options. It causes psql to issue a BEGIN command
>              before the first such option and a COMMIT command after the last one, thereby wrapping all the commands into a single
>              transaction. This ensures that either all the commands complete successfully, or no changes are applied.